# How do I choose a photo for my user account in Hera?

Tags: release-hera, user

I'm trying to change my profile photo in Hera, but I don't see my own account under "User Account Settings":

[image: User Account window not showing my current account.]

How can I get my account to show and thus change my personal details?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't change the profile photo of guest account.

Comment: Right, but my question was really how to change my own (main user). Just trying to replace the photo on the greeter, for now.

Comment: @FredRocha Login to your account, go to user account settings, and click on your profile photo. Look at this: https://cdn.fosslinux.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/06234926/User-Accounts.jpg

Comment: If you look at the screenshot in my question you'll see my own profile isn't showing. That is the culprit.